# HTML form's input text starts from the middle

Tags: html, css, forms

So in general I am working on my own portfolio, but I've ran into one issue.
I've created a text entry box that is 140x40 but sadly the text starts from the middle.

It what it looks like:

[image]

It shouldn't be starting fromt he middle, but top left

Any ideas? this is the default form with little to none styling.

```
form .form_button
{
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    background-color: rgb( 241, 101, 76 );
    border: none;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: The CSS you've provided, is for the class `form_button` is the class that that input field is using? I suspect it's not. Could you post everything from `<form>` to `</form>`? And any other CSS styling for the form that you can see?

Comment: I think @indubitablee has it. It will help if you post your HTML as well next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your message should be in a `<textarea></textarea>` not a regular input type text

see the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/92/

Comment: But can I send it to access it via $_POST later?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the element you have created is an  You should consider changing it to a text area. Then the text will align where you expect.

If you can't change it to  try adding vertical-align: text-top; to your input.